# How to use readonly() method to Kendo UI datetime input created with AngualrJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

In this [page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#methods-readonly])i found this example

```
<input id="datepicker" />

<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
vardatepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
datepicker.readonly();</script>
```

How can use this readonly function to datetime input created by Angular?
[example of datetime with angular](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/angular)

I want to add disabled input using only AngularJs
At my code:

```
                    <input kendo-date-picker
                       id="linesDateObject"
                       k-options="linesPickDateOptions"
                       k-ng-model="linesDateObject"
                       style="width:200px;"
                       class="pull-left" />
```

In my controller

```
    $scope.linesPickDateOptions = {
    value: new Date(),
    format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
    change: function () {
        var value = this.value();
        console.log(value);
    }

}
```

I want to add disable property inside $scope.linesPickDateOptions object

Answer (score 0):

$('#datepicker').data('kendoDatePicker').enable(false);

Comment: i dont want to use jquery..i just want to enable it from k-options with angular. It is possible?

Comment: $("#datepicker").prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");

Comment: still no...look at my upgrade post

Comment: you have given change method and same time you want disable ..something need to be corrected

Comment: actually i want only keyboard input disabled, not date selector

Comment: <input id="datepicker" disabled /> this will only work